# Grails log4j version clash with a third party java API

Tags: grails, log4j

I have to use a third party Java API from Cisco which uses an older version of Log4J i.e. 1.1.3
When run standalone, obviously API works fine but when run from Grails (1.3.7), it crashes with some "Operation not found" exception during Log4j initialization.

How can I resolve this clash?

Here is the BuildConfig actual plugin that contains the cisco lib in the lib folder.

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.plugin.location.'advoss-orm-core' = "../../../advoss-orm-core-grails-plugin/branches/ShahbazORMPlugin"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        flatDir  name:"lib", dirs:"lib"
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16') {
            transitive = false
        }
        compile ':command:1.0',
                ':commons-codec:1.3',
                ':commons-httpclient:3.1',
                ':commons-logging:1.1.1',
                ':deltawing:1.0',
                ':deltaxml:1.0',
                ':isorelax:1.0',
                ':jhall:1.0',
                ':jing:1.0',
                ':junit-dep:4.9b2',
                ':marklogic-xcc:4.2.2',
                ':metadata-extractor:2.3.1',
                ':msv:1.0',
                ':resolver:1.0',
                ':saxon:9pe',
                ':tagsoup:1.2',
                ':xep:1.0',
                ':xmlunit:1.3'
    }
}
```

Now here is the build config of the project that includes the above plugin and fails to execute Cisco library calls with Log4j errors:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.plugin.location.'adv-provisioning-server' = "../../../adv-provisioning-server/branches/AlamSher_AdvProvisioningServer"
grails.plugin.location.'advoss-orm-core' = "../../../advoss-orm-core-grails-plugin/branches/ShahbazORMPlugin"
//grails.plugin.location.'advoss-trouble-ticket' = "../../../advoss-trouble-ticket-grails-plugin/branches/ShahbazTroubleTicketPlugin"

//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    remoteRepository(id: "release", url: "http://192.168.0.2:8080/artifactory/plugins-release-local") {
        authentication username: "maven_user", password: "mav3nus3r"
    }
}

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    pom true

    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16') {
            transitive = false
        }
        compile 'jaxfront:jaxfront-html:1.0',
                'jaxfront:jaxfront-pdf:1.0',
                'jaxfront:jaxfront-core:1.0',
                'advoss-voms:VomsWSClient:1.0',
                'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7',
                'freemarker:freemarker:2.3.9',
//                'net.sourceforge.barbecue:barbecue:1.5-beta1',
//                'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:4.0.0',
//                'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-javaflow:3.7.5',
                'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1',
                'commons-net:commons-net:20030805.205232'
//        compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:4.0.1') {
//            transitive = false
//        }
        compile('net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:4.1.2') {
            excludes 'poi-ooxml', 'antlr', 'commons-beanutils',
                    'commons-collections', 'commons-logging',
                    'ant', 'mondrian', 'commons-javaflow',
                    'barbecue', 'xml-apis-ext', 'xml-apis',
                    'xalan', 'groovy-all', 'hibernate',
                    'saaj-api', 'servlet-api', 'xercesImpl', 'xmlParserAPIs',
                    'spring-core', 'bsh', 'spring-beans', 'jaxen',
                    'barcode4j', 'batik-svg-dom', 'batik-xml',
                    'batik-awt-util', 'batik-dom', 'batik-css',
                    'batik-gvt', 'batik-script', 'batik-svggen',
                    'batik-util', 'batik-bridge', 'persistence-api',
                    'jdtcore', 'bcmail-jdk14', 'bcprov-jdk14', 'bctsp-jdk14'
        }
    }

    plugins {
        compile ':jsecurity:0.4.1',
                ':message-digest:1.1',
                ':quartz:0.4.2',
                ':export:0.7',
                ':jquery:1.4.4.1',
                ':jquery-ui:1.8.2',
                ':xml-validator:0.1',
                ':advoss-orm-core:1.0.2.0',
        compile (':adv-provisioning-server:1.0.0.1') {
            excludes('commons-httpclient')
        }
        runtime(':jasper:1.2') { excludes 'jasperreports' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance Cisco has an updated .jar that uses a more recent version of log4j? 1.2.x has been available since 2004; that's more than time enough for them to upgrade their library.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're running into clashing dependencies.

Suppose the Third-party Cisco library was resolved from maven with this artifact string: `"com.cisco.foo"`. You would add a closure after the part of `BuildConfig.groovy` to exclude the Log4J transitive dependency, like so:

```
dependencies {
  // ... other dependencies
  compile("com.cisco.foo") {
    excludes "log4j"
  }
}
```

This will effectively just exclude the Log4J 1.1.3 that was included by the Cisco lib.

EDIT: If the JAR is just in `lib/` instead of the bits above, IIRC you can do something like:

```
dependencies {
  // ... other dependencies
  inherits("global") {
    excludes "log4j"
  }
}
```

In that case, though, is log4j 1.1.3 in the `lib/` directory as well or is the Cisco JAR a fat jar with the Log4J classes. The latter case may be much tricker and you should add that to you question if so.

Comment: Cisco library jar is just in the project lib folder and not resolved from BuildConfig. Will the above still work?

Comment: Sorry, was busy in something else. Yes it appears to be a fat jar. It gives me error 'NoSuchMethodError' on some RollingFileAppender If I provide it with a different version of Log4j than 1.1.3

Comment: Could you post as much of your BuildConfig.groovy as you can?

Comment: Please check if this helps you figure out things. I edited the question to post required BuildConfig files.

Comment: I can't tell from the config files where the log4j dependency is coming from. A couple things you can do: Run `grails dependencyReport` and see which lib includes log4j and exclude it under that dependency. You can also try excluding "log4j" from the Cisco lib and including your own.